# Pages not showing on side menu

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, docutils

I am using Sphinx and ReStructuredText to create documentation, but even though all pages were created the same way, only 4 out of 8 are showing on the side menu. This is my table of contents:

```
.. toctree::

   :glob:
   :titlesonly:
   
   *
```

I've tried to add the pages manually, but it didn't seem to work either.
Here's the link to the documentation where you can find the source code: [Docs](https://documentation-senografia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: In your `conf.py`, the value for [`html_sidebars`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_sidebars) is not correct for your Sphinx theme. You don't have custom templates in your repo. Remove this value, and try again.

Comment: I tried it, but it's still only showing half of the pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use either correct syntax of the `toctree` directive when using its options, or use file names whose casing aligns with what you put in the `toctree` directive.

The `.rst` files in your directory are the following.

```
Coordenadas.rst
Galeria-mapa.rst
Home-page.rst
Lista-camadas.rst
index.rst
legenda.rst
marcador.rst
medicao.rst
oscilar.rst
```

But in your `index.rst` you use the incorrect case for those filenames, and you add a blank line between the file names and glob character without using the `glob` option.

```
.. toctree::

   Home-page
   Coordenadas
   Galeria-mapa
   Legenda
   Lista-camadas
   Marcador
   Medicao
   Oscilar

   *
```

By looking at the [build log on Read The Docs](https://readthedocs.org/api/v2/build/19297476.txt), you would find several warnings indicating what went wrong.

`/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/documentation-senografia/checkouts/latest/docs/source/index.rst:5: WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document 'Legenda'`

To fix it, this is one option.

```
.. toctree::

   Home-page
   Coordenadas
   Galeria-mapa
   legenda
   Lista-camadas
   marcador
   medicao
   oscilar
```

And this should work, too. Note that in this version compared to yours, the options are immediately after the `toctree` directive without a blank line between them. A blank line should be present before the first `toctree` entry.

```
.. toctree::
    :glob:
    :titlesonly:

    *
```

Comment: I didn't notice that, but that helped me a lot, thank you!